# Use of 'the' in sentence: "Watch the birds in the sky"

Tags: grammar

During learning English with 'Grammar' app from British Council I have noticed one sentence which confused me and that's why I'd like to ask you:
Why do we have to use 'the' before birds in this sentence:
"Watch THE birds in the sky"
I thought that we use the in cases when we talk about something specific or something that was mentioned earlier?

Comment: Aren't the birds that are in the sky right now, and are visible, 'specific'?

Comment: *Why do we have to use 'the' before birds in this sentence?* The obvious answer is ***We don't have to**!* But we ***do*** have to include the article before ***sky*** in such a context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use ***the*** before a noun, there is an underlying relative clause that we commonly omit:

> Watch ***THE*** birds [that are visible/are now flying] in the sky

The emphasis is on those particular birds on that particular occasion. Yet, this is not absolute, there are instances with ***the*** that do not necessarily intend to particularise the birds (see example 3 below).

> Watch birds in the sky

***without the***, can also exist, but the emphasis is not on ***which particular birds*** you watch, but on the action of watching (often called ***birdwatching***).

Compare:

> 1. When I *watch birds* in the sky, moving together in a flock, I’m constantly amazed by their ability to move as one. ([source](https://bitrebels.com/geek/swarm-amazing-video-of-birds-in-flight/))

with

> 2. As he *watched the birds* in the sky, he tried to make few drawings​ ([source](https://brainly.in/question/28455895))

but also with

> 3. Have you ever stopped to watch the birds in the sky? ([source](http://www.adventurebimbling.com/why-should-you-buy-binoculars-for-the-next-birdwatching-season-in-australia/))

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=watch%20the%20birds%2C%20watch%20birds&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwatch%20the%20birds%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwatch%20birds%3B%2Cc0) will show that both exist, but that ***with birds*** is presently in decline. People prefer the use with "the".